# Unit testing a loop over a set

Tags: unit-testing

Suppose I have the following (Java) code:

```java
class MyObject {
  private int demo;
  /* ...further properties... */
  /* ...getters, setters... */
}

class TestMe {
  public static Set<MyObject> processAll(Set<MyObject> input) {
    Set<MyObject> result = new HashSet<>();
    for(final MyObject entry : input) {
      result.add(process(input));
    }
    return result;
  }
  private static MyObject process(MyObject input) {
    MyObject result = new MyObject();
    result.setDemo(input.getDemo() + 1);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a test for this code. It would be easy to write a test for the process-method. The resulting Object should have a value for "demo" that is one larger than the input Object and the input object was not changed. And since the method is private I would like to avoid testing that method anyway.

However I would like to test that the processAll method works with an empty set (easy), works with one entry in the set (easy as well) and works with multiple elements in the set (here is my problem).

Because the result is a Set, the order of elements in the result of processAll is undefined and I cannot simply test that the first element is X and the second element is Y. I cannot use some simple `actual.containsAll(expected) && expected.containsAll(actual)` magic, because the equals method if MyObject checks for identity only (and it does not make sense to change that).

I tried to sort the input and output of processAll by writing my own Comparator, adding all elements to a SortedSet and then iterating over both sets, assuming that the demo property of the output-1 equals the input. But I found that my assertion code has grown large and hard to understand.

Is there any "best practice"-way to deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the difficulty of using `containsAll`. That is not the only way of examining the content of a set. You could also iterate through its members, setting a flag when you find an expected object, then after the loop checking that all the flags were set.

Answer (score 0):

I try to be pragmatic regarding unit tests.

You can have a simple test for the "set is empty" case.

You can have a simple test for the "set contains a single element" case. This test covers the transformation and the loop.

You can have a simple test that checks that the size of the output is equal to the size of the input.

Now, all of your code is covered, and an additional test would only ensure that your code doesn't do something different for sets with more than 1 element. But the probability of such a problem is very very close to 0. So such a complex test wouldn't add anything valuable, but would be hard to understand and maintain. And even if you had a test for 10 elements, it wouldn't cover the case (also highly improbable) where the code would do something different for sets having 11 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need complex assertion logic, you might want to think about writing that logic in the form of a Hamcrest [Matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) rather than cluttering your test code with it directly.

It might be that one of the standard [matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) supplied with Hamcrest is useful to you, though given the difficulty you seem to have with the standard set comparison techniques, that seems unlikely.

If you're using a recent version of JUnit, it probably includes these, and you can use the JUnit [assertThat](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) methods with them.